# PyTorch with Transformer - finetune GPT2 throws index out of range Error

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface, gpt-2

in my Jupiter i have the following code. I can not figure out why this throws a `IndexError: index out of range in self` error.

here ist the code:

```
!pip install torch
!pip install torchvision
!pip install transformers
```

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset

class MakeDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, tokenized_texts, block_size):
        self.examples = []
        for tokens in tokenized_texts:
            # truncate the tokens if they are longer than block_size
            if len(tokens) > block_size:
                tokens = tokens[:block_size]
            # add padding tokens if the tokens are shorter than block_size
            while len(tokens) < block_size:
                tokens.append(tokenizer.pad_token_id)
            self.examples.append(torch.tensor(tokens, dtype=torch.long))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.examples)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.examples[item]
```

```
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling, Trainer, TrainingArguments, AutoTokenizer, \
    AutoModelWithLMHead, GPT2Tokenizer

# Load the tokenizer and model
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2', padding_side='right')
model = AutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained('gpt2')

PAD_TOKEN = '<PAD>'
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': PAD_TOKEN})

# Load text corpus
with open("texts.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    texts = f.read().splitlines()

print(len(texts) , " lines of text.")

# Tokenize the texts
tokenized_texts = []
for text in texts:
    tokens = tokenizer.encode(text, padding='max_length', truncation='only_first')
    if len(tokens) > 0:
        tokenized_texts.append(tokens)

# gemerate a dataset
dataset = MakeDataset(tokenized_texts, block_size=1024)
print("Dataset length: ", len(dataset))


# Create a DataCollatorForLanguageModeling object
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False)

# Define the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',  # output directory
    num_train_epochs=5,  # total number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # batch size per device during training
    save_steps=1000,  # number of steps between saving checkpoints
    save_total_limit=2,  # limit the total amount of checkpoints saved
    prediction_loss_only=True,  # only calculate loss on prediction tokens
    learning_rate=1e-5,  # learning rate
    warmup_steps=500,  # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    fp16=False  # enable mixed precision training with apex
)

# Create a Trainer object
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=dataset
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()

# Save the trained model
trainer.save_model('./fine-tuned-gpt2')
```

The text file at the moment looks very simple:

```
Hello, my name is Paul.
My cat can sing.
```

The full error is:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[140], line 54
     46 trainer = Trainer(
     47     model=model,
     48     args=training_args,
     49     data_collator=data_collator,
     50     train_dataset=dataset
     51 )
     53 # Train the model
---> 54 trainer.train()
     56 # Save the trained model
     57 trainer.save_model('./fine-tuned-gpt2')

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1633, in Trainer.train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval, **kwargs)
   1628     self.model_wrapped = self.model
   1630 inner_training_loop = find_executable_batch_size(
   1631     self._inner_training_loop, self._train_batch_size, args.auto_find_batch_size
   1632 )
-> 1633 return inner_training_loop(
   1634     args=args,
   1635     resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
   1636     trial=trial,
   1637     ignore_keys_for_eval=ignore_keys_for_eval,
   1638 )

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1902, in Trainer._inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)
   1900         tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1901 else:
-> 1902     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
   1904 if (
   1905     args.logging_nan_inf_filter
   1906     and not is_torch_tpu_available()
   1907     and (torch.isnan(tr_loss_step) or torch.isinf(tr_loss_step))
   1908 ):
   1909     # if loss is nan or inf simply add the average of previous logged losses
   1910     tr_loss += tr_loss / (1 + self.state.global_step - self._globalstep_last_logged)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2645, in Trainer.training_step(self, model, inputs)
   2642     return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)
   2644 with self.compute_loss_context_manager():
-> 2645     loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
   2647 if self.args.n_gpu > 1:
   2648     loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2677, in Trainer.compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs)
   2675 else:
   2676     labels = None
-> 2677 outputs = model(**inputs)
   2678 # Save past state if it exists
   2679 # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.
   2680 if self.args.past_index >= 0:

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py:1075, in GPT2LMHeadModel.forward(self, input_ids, past_key_values, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, labels, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1067 r"""
   1068 labels (`torch.LongTensor` of shape `(batch_size, sequence_length)`, *optional*):
   1069     Labels for language modeling. Note that the labels **are shifted** inside the model, i.e. you can set
   1070     `labels = input_ids` Indices are selected in `[-100, 0, ..., config.vocab_size]` All labels set to `-100`
   1071     are ignored (masked), the loss is only computed for labels in `[0, ..., config.vocab_size]`
   1072 """
   1073 return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return_dict
-> 1075 transformer_outputs = self.transformer(
   1076     input_ids,
   1077     past_key_values=past_key_values,
   1078     attention_mask=attention_mask,
   1079     token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
   1080     position_ids=position_ids,
   1081     head_mask=head_mask,
   1082     inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
   1083     encoder_hidden_states=encoder_hidden_states,
   1084     encoder_attention_mask=encoder_attention_mask,
   1085     use_cache=use_cache,
   1086     output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1087     output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
   1088     return_dict=return_dict,
   1089 )
   1090 hidden_states = transformer_outputs[0]
   1092 # Set device for model parallelism

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/models/gpt2/modeling_gpt2.py:842, in GPT2Model.forward(self, input_ids, past_key_values, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    839 head_mask = self.get_head_mask(head_mask, self.config.n_layer)
    841 if inputs_embeds is None:
--> 842     inputs_embeds = self.wte(input_ids)
    843 position_embeds = self.wpe(position_ids)
    844 hidden_states = inputs_embeds + position_embeds

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py:162, in Embedding.forward(self, input)
    161 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 162     return F.embedding(
    163         input, self.weight, self.padding_idx, self.max_norm,
    164         self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:2210, in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2204     # Note [embedding_renorm set_grad_enabled]
   2205     # XXX: equivalent to
   2206     # with torch.no_grad():
   2207     #   torch.embedding_renorm_
   2208     # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2209     _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2210 return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)

IndexError: index out of range in self
```

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong with the training setup?

++ UPDATE ++

I change the `MakeDataset` to `TextDataset` to get a pt tensor back:

```
class TextDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings):
        self.encodings = encodings

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {key: tensor[idx] for key, tensor in self.encodings.items()}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings.input_ids)
```

the output of `print(dataset[0])` is:

```
{'input_ids': tensor([15496,    11,   616,  1438,   318,  3362,    13, 50257, 50257, 50257,
        50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257, 50257,
        50257, 50257]), 'attention_mask': tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])}
```

and with

```
tokenized_texts = tokenizer(texts, padding='max_length', truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
```

to pad them to the models length:

```
6  lines of text.
Dataset length:  6
{'input_ids': tensor([[15496,    11,   616,  ..., 50257, 50257, 50257],
        [ 3666,  3797,   460,  ..., 50257, 50257, 50257],
        [32423,  1408, 46097,  ..., 50257, 50257, 50257],
        [10020,  1044,  6877,  ..., 50257, 50257, 50257],
        [31319,   288,   292,  ..., 50257, 50257, 50257],
        [ 7447, 24408,  8834,  ..., 50257, 50257, 50257]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0]])}
```

But I still get the same error.
I also deleted all caches.

Comment: I had this same issue. I have mine setup to pickle the input_ids and attention_mask and load if from disk. Even though I though I had done it multiple times, I was able to solve it by recomputing the tokens. Maybe look to see if the dataset is cached somewhere.

Comment: I deleted all caches, and also update the dataset class. (See update of post). But still the same problem.